# RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^www*.kerala\.local [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.kerala.local/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am getting the error in browser:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@cyberotech.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

The `/var/log/apache2/error.log` says:

```
RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '*!^www*.kerala\\.local'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is indeed wrong. (there are stray asterisks)

Use this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It is workin ,. Can you provide a generic solution irrespective of domain name